# Python requests (Ubuntu): first requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool GET response VERY slow but every one after per session extremely fast

Tags: ubuntu, networking

This is a very weird problem and I am not sure how to fix it, but it's killing the performance of an app I am building.

In my python app, I use rpyc to start a threaded server that listens for requests.  When it gets a request, which in this case is just a passed URL, it takes the URL and downloads it to do some other stuff to it.

The download should be instantaneous (100M down/up connection) but it stalls for upwards of 20 seconds on what looks like some funky type of DNS timeout, but only the very first time within any python "session."  So if I load up iPython, load my libraries, attempt to download an article the first time, it stalls-- but if I do it again after the first, and every time after, it is as fast as it should be.

Very weird.

The base package is requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool (I'm using this via the newspaper library, but it does the same thing if I use the requests library directly) and the debug doesn't show anything but that it takes a long time to get that first GET.  So, I decided to run tcpdump in the background, and this is what it looks like.

The output for the first/initial one is here-- you can see that it takes 20 seconds from start to finish before the operation completes.  The weird thing is that resolver1-fs.opendns.com.domain response in there.  I have no idea where that's coming from.  But it looks like it's screwing something up.  You can see in the next snippet what I EXPECT to happen (and what happens every time thereafter.)

```
00:14:19.512317 IP 10.10.10.10.57771 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 27177+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:19.512323 IP 10.10.10.10.57771 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 4945+ AAAA? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:19.516199 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.57771: 4945 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., AAAA 2606:2800:221:18cd:1493:1b94:ea5:557 (154)
00:14:19.622120 IP resolver1-fs.opendns.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.57771: 27177 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., A 152.195.54.95 (142)
00:14:24.517261 IP 10.10.10.10.57771 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 27177+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:29.522261 IP 10.10.10.10.57771 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 27177+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:34.527351 IP 10.10.10.10.50963 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 44146+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:34.529688 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.50963: 44146 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., A 152.195.54.95 (142)
00:14:34.529730 IP 10.10.10.10.50963 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 8868+ AAAA? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:39.531792 IP 10.10.10.10.47933 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 44146+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:39.629774 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.47933: 44146 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., A 152.195.54.95 (142)
00:14:39.629841 IP 10.10.10.10.47451 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 8868+ AAAA? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:14:39.696671 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.47451: 8868 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., AAAA 2606:2800:221:18cd:1493:1b94:ea5:557 (154)
```

Here's the second tcpdump.  If I do it again immediately (it is the same no matter if it's a different domain name, I'm doing huffingtonpost again because of how the tcpdump filter I used is setup) the results are blazing fast:

```
00:15:09.575741 IP 10.10.10.10.47420 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 11015+ A? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:15:09.642151 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.47420: 11015 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., A 152.195.54.95 (142)
00:15:09.642229 IP 10.10.10.10.57342 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 40060+ AAAA? www.huffingtonpost.com. (40)
00:15:09.708198 IP google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > 10.10.10.10.57342: 40060 3/0/0 CNAME www.huffingtonpost.com.huffpost.akadns.net., CNAME cs593.adn.mucdn.net., AAAA 2606:2800:221:18cd:1493:1b94:ea5:557 (154)
```

What the heck is the deal with this? It almost seems like a network error but I have no idea how to fix it.  This system is behind an ASUS router and /etc/resolv.conf uses the google DNS:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

The problem is that every time my rpyc server thread is called, it's as if it's the first time it's calling this (as if it's got to initialized itself for every new threaded instance) so the response time is killing me.  This thing should respond in under a second and it's taking 20-30 seconds.

Anybody have any idea what the hell is going on?  It's not an rpyc thing because I can verify that running two seperate ipython sessions at the same time, it's insular to a single python 'instance.'

It did not used to work this way.  Something broke a few weeks ago, not sure what I did.  I did muck around with some php and apache for a site I host, but I can't imagine that would have caused this to behave so weird.

Thanks in advance, I'm at a loss.  I really am not sure what I did to break it.  The only thing I've done to the networking on this machine is to turn IPV6 off because it was REALLY slowing down all my network activity. That was a few months ago though, and up until fairly recently, this worked as expected.

Hodor.

EDIT: curl/wget are just as slow from the command line, as I was prompted to check.  Here's the output of wget on this page:

```
wget https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232544/python-requests-ubuntu-first-requests-packages-urllib3-connectionpool-get-res
--2017-09-15 00:59:52--  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232544/python-requests-ubuntu-first-requests-packages-urllib3-connectionpool-get-res
Resolving stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)... 151.101.1.69, 151.101.65.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to stackoverflow.com (stackoverflow.com)|151.101.1.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 98486 (96K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘python-requests-ubuntu-first-requests-packages-urllib3-connectionpool-get-res’

python-requests-ubuntu-first-requests-packages-u 100%[=======================================================================================================>]  96.18K  --.-KB/s    in 0.05s

2017-09-15 01:00:12 (1.94 MB/s) - ‘python-requests-ubuntu-first-requests-packages-urllib3-connectionpool-get-res’ saved [98486/98486]
```

Comment: What happens when you just try the same request with something like curl or wget.

Comment: Same thing.  Super duper slow. I updated my answer with what the wget output looks like for getting this page.

Comment: So, wait, where is the slow in wget? in the resolving and connecting part? What takes 15 seconds, etc? Since this is narrowing down to a network thing rather than a programming thing, you might have better luck on [SF]

Comment: Resolving. Ping works fine, resolves right away.  Not sure what the dilly-o us.  I'll try server fault, great idea.  Thanks.